Is it possible to publish multiple sites on port 80 on a single server in Docker?
First of all, I should mention that I am not good at docker. And thank you in advance for your help.
A Laravel project is currently running on Docker on a VPS server (this site will be called a.com)
For a.com I am sharing below docker-compose-production.yaml and nginx.conf
docker-compose-production.yml:
networks:
    default:
        driver: bridge

services:
  a.com:
    restart: always
    build: .docker/prod/php
    container_name: acom_php
    networks:
      - default
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx:stable
    container_name: a_nginx
    networks:
      - default
    links:
      - a.com
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
      - .docker/prod/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - .docker/prod/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot/
      - ./certbot/conf/:/etc/nginx/ssl/
    depends_on:
      - a.com
      - mysql
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/
      - ./certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt/
    depends_on:
      - nginx
  mysql:
    restart: unless-stopped
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: acom_db
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - 1300:3306
    volumes:
      - .docker/prod/db/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - .docker/prod/logs:/var/log/mysql
      - .docker/prod/db/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
      - .docker/prod/db/sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: acom_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: acom
      MYSQL_USER: acom_laravel
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: acom_secret
  phpmyadmin:
    restart: unless-stopped
    platform: linux/amd64
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: acom_phpmyadmin
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 300M
      PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT: 2048M
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - .docker/prod/phpmyadmin/sessions:/sessions

nginx.conf:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name a.com a.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://a.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name a.com;
  return 301 https://a.com$request_uri;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/a.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/a.com/privkey.pem;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  http2 on;
  server_name a.com a.com;
  index index.php index.html;
  root /var/www/public;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/a.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/a.com/privkey.pem;

  client_max_body_size 300M; # 413 Request Entity Too Large
 
  index index.php;
 
  charset utf-8;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }

  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

  error_page 404 /index.php;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass a_php:9000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    send_timeout 3600;
    proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
    proxy_read_timeout    3600;
    proxy_send_timeout    3600;
  }
}

With the above settings, a.com works fine without any problems.
My main problem is when I want to use the same settings for b.com Laravel project: Bind for 0.0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated error. I understand the cause of this error and set the ports in docker-compose-production.yaml for b.com to be different and docker starts working.
Assume I am using the following ports for the b.com site.

ports

8001:80 # nginx 80
8002:443 # nginx 443
1301:3306 # mysql 3306
8081:80 # phpmyadmin



nginx.conf: (for testing purposes)
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name b.com www.b.com;
    root /var/www/public;
    server_tokens off;

    client_max_body_size 300M; # 413 Request Entity Too Large
  
    index index.php;
  
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass bcom_php:9000;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
      send_timeout 3600;
      proxy_connect_timeout 3600;
      proxy_read_timeout    3600;
      proxy_send_timeout    3600;
    }
}


I run each project with docker compose up -d --build command

With these settings, when Docker runs and I visit b.com, it automatically redirects me to a.com. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, I think it automatically redirects me to a.com because port 80 is currently on the other Docker container.
I would be very grateful if you can help me.

You can't have both containers (a.com and b.com) using port 80 on the same host at the same time.

Thank you for your comment. What do I need to do to publish more than one site on a single server? @RaviChauhan

You'd need to add both sites to the same single reverse proxy you already have.  If this is for development purposes especially, you might find it easier to avoid host-based routing (you wind up having to hack in multiple things repeatedly to make a.example.com resolve at all) and prefer path-based routing (http://localhost/a/ and http://localhost/b/ point at the two applications).

Does this mean that multiple sites should run on a single docker-container? If I am going to set up reverse-proxy logic, I guess I need to create a single docker environment for 5 sites.

Ok now I understand and I did what you mean. For this I installed nginx on the VPS server and ran all Docker containers. Then I set it as a proxy to Docker ports with nginx reverse-proxy. Everything seems to be fine now. Thanks for your help. @DavidMaze

You are using root /var/www/public for both a.com and b.com and in your docker-compose file you have in a.com volumes mapping - .:/var/www
You need to either find a way to map your two projects to separate directories in your nginx container or in case your Laravel project is a standalone project you could use nginx as a reverse proxy and use something like proxy_pass: b.com:port for your b.com configuration in nginx.
